# Load signature to vue-signature-pad

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am beginner in vue.
I have my firs post here. I make my project in Vue 2.

I have this code: https://pastebin.com/Ddaqf6E9

```
<vue-signature-pad
                          id="signature"
                          width="100%"
                          height="500px"
                          ref="signaturePad"
                          :options="{
                            onBegin: () => {$refs.signaturePad.resizeCanvas()},
                            images: () => { 'https://a.allegroimg.com/s1024/11837d/f04da35e4213a6f817918924c51f/8BitDo-ADAPTER-GRAJ-PADEM-PS4-XBOX-NA-SWITCH-PC-Sposob-podlaczenia-bezprzewodowy'}
                        }"
                        />
```

This is work fine. When I click on cavas - I can painting.

Now, I need add signature from database to this canvas (after page reload).
I can create image in php. For test I try add to canvas this image: https://a.allegroimg.com/s1024/11837d/f04da35e4213a6f817918924c51f/8BitDo-ADAPTER-GRAJ-PADEM-PS4-XBOX-NA-SWITCH-PC-Sposob-podlaczenia-bezprzewodowy

but it's not visible :(

How can I repair it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-signature-pad-demo-forked-sc2yg5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

```js
...
  async mounted() {  
 
 
 fetch("https://a.allegroimg.com/s1024/11837d/f04da35e4213a6f817918924c51f/8BitDo-ADAPTER-GRAJ-PADEM-PS4-XBOX-NA-SWITCH-PC-Sposob-podlaczenia-bezprzewodowy")
    .then(raw => raw.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.$refs.signaturePad.fromDataURL(reader.result)
      }
    })
  }
...
```

Comment: its return me error: [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: regeneratorRuntime"

found in

---> <EditTask> at src/views/task/EditTask.vue
       <Anonymous>
         <CWrapper>
           <TheContainer> at src/containers/TheContainer.vue
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>

Comment: Not related to this. Create a new question.

Comment: @taunzN can you help me in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996273/add-signature-from-base64-blob-in-vue-signature-pad ?